# Parameter not being read from SOAP request

Tags: c#, .net, asmx

I'm having a problem with a web service that I'm writing (it's asmx).

I have this method:

```
    [WebMethod()]
    [SoapDocumentMethod(
        RequestNamespace="http://bsp.XXX.org",
        ResponseNamespace="http://bsp.XXX.org",
        ResponseElementName="PaymentResults",
        RequestElementName="GetPaymentResult",
        Action = "http://bsp.XXX.org/GetPaymentResult")]
    public PaymentResult[] GetPaymentResult(string MerchantRef)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(MerchantRef))
            {
                return PaymentResultRepository.GetPaymentResults(MerchantRef).ToArray();
            }
            else
            {
                _errorLog.Error("MerchantRef is empty");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _errorLog.Error("Failed to get payment details", ex);
        }
        return new PaymentResult[0];
    }
}
```

And it's being called from an Oracle Forms application. The SOAP request received is:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <GetPaymentResult xmlns="http://bsp.XXX.org/" 
                 SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
            <MerchantRef xsi:type="xsd:string">
                 IP/58991/1
            </MerchantRef>
        </GetPaymentResult>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
```

The problem is that "MerchantRef" is always an empty string in my method... Anyone have any idea about this? Is the SOAP request wrong? Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that the problem was the SOAP request...

It didn't like the encodingStyle attribute, once this was removed it worked perfectly.

i.e. from this:

```
<GetPaymentResult xmlns="http://bsp.XXX.org/" 
             SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
```

to:

```
<GetPaymentResult xmlns="http://bsp.XXX.org/">
```